# Inject property into web api filter Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a small filter

```
public class Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public IMyclass myClass { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // pre-processing
        Debug.WriteLine("ACTION 1 DEBUG pre-processing logging");
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (objectContent != null)
        {
            var type = objectContent.ObjectType; //type of the returned object
            var value = objectContent.Value; //holding the returned value
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("ACTION 1 DEBUG  OnActionExecuted Response " + actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
}
```

I would like for `IMyclass` to have injected a class that gets resolved from AutoFac.

```
builder.RegisterType<IMyclass >().As<MyClass>().InstancePerRequest();
```

however it is still `null`. All my other injections are working fine in the constructor but not in the property.

Comment: _All my other injections are working fine in the constructor but not in the property_ : I'm confused: your attribute has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: not used autofac but see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906329/autofac-attribute-injection-failing-on-attributes does `PropertiesAutowired` have anything to do with it? ie registering your attribute `builder.RegisterType<Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter>().PropertiesAutowired()`

Comment: @FabioSalvalai you can use property injection too!

Comment: of course, Ric. The thing is that this attribute has no .ctor, therefore no .ctor injections. @TotalWar claims the other injections work fine in the .ctor, and therefore assumes the IoC does his job. but since there is no injection in the .ctor, you can't draw that conclusion. My guess is: the attribute is not resolved by the IoC container, and therefore, no injections, property or otherwise, are performed.

Comment: Agreed, see my anser.

Answer (score 3):

Attributes are not DI-friendly at all. They are instantiated by the .NET framework, so you have no control over what dependencies they have. So, the best solution is to abandon the thought of using `ActionFilterAttribute` altogether.

As pointed out in [passive attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/), you can break down your `ActionFilterAttribute` into its 2 inherited features:

1. An `Attribute` subclass (that does not contain any behavior).
2. A DI-friendly [`IActionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter(v=vs.100).aspx) subclass (that uses constructor injection).

---

### Action1DebugAttribute

First, there is the attribute to mark your controllers and actions with. This attribute contains no behavior at all (but it may contain properties like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245220/how-can-i-test-for-the-presence-of-an-action-filter-with-constructor-arguments/27470397#27470397) if desired).

```
// This attribute should contain no behavior. No behavior, nothing needs to be injected.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class Action1DebugAttribute : Attribute
{}
```

### Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter

This is the DI-friendly action filter. We can use constructor injection or property injection if desired. This example uses constructor injection for the sake of simplicity.

```
public class Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IMyclass myClass;

    public Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        if (myClass == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("myClass");
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (this.IsFilterDefined(actionContext.ActionDescriptor))
        {
            // pre-processing
            Debug.WriteLine("ACTION 1 DEBUG pre-processing logging");
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (this.IsFilterDefined(actionExecutedContext.ActionDescriptor))
        {
            var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
            if (objectContent != null)
            {
                var type = objectContent.ObjectType; //type of the returned object
                var value = objectContent.Value; //holding the returned value
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("ACTION 1 DEBUG  OnActionExecuted Response " + actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }

    private bool IsFilterDefined(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Action1DebugAttribute), inherit: true)
            || actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(Action1DebugAttribute), inherit: true);
    }
}
```

### Usage

Once you do this, you can simply use Autofac to resolve your action filter and all of its dependencies in your composition root.

#### Registration

```
builder.RegisterType<IMyclass>().As<MyClass>();
// Since it is possible more than one `IActionFilter` is registered,
// we are using a named type. You could alternatively create another 
// interface to uniquely identify this action filter.
builder.RegisterType<IActionFilter>()
       .Named<Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter>("action1DebugActionWebApiFilter");
```

#### Resolving

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, IContainer container)
    {
        filters.Add(container.ResolveNamed<IActionFilter>("action1DebugActionWebApiFilter"));
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

### Lifetime

You won't be able to use instance per request lifetime because action filters are created as part of MVC's object graph, not resolved per request.

However, your desire to do so indicates that the `IMyClass` instance has some state in it that applies to the current request. If that is not the case, then you can use this code as is.

On the other hand, if your object is stateful, then you can use one of the following approaches to resolve it at runtime:

1. Inject an [Abstract Factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) that creates your `MyClass` instance instead of injecting the class directly into the filter.
2. Inject a `Func<Type, IMyClass>` into the filter in order to call an anonymous method inside of your composition root that uses the container to resolve the instance [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950362/factory-method-with-di-and-ioc#31956803).

Comment: 'You won't be able to use instance per request lifetime because action filters are created as part of MVC's object graph, not resolved per request.'   I was actually planning to do a database call to get a user's roles from his id ( that i get from his claim).

Comment: In that case, just use an abstract factory to instantiate your dbcontext into a using block so it is disposed of properly.

Comment: 'You won't be able to use instance per request lifetime because action filters are created as part of MVC's object graph, not resolved per request.' Are you sure this still holds? The autofac doucmentation still says so, but i'm using an  IAutofacActionFilter on an application i'm developing, and i'm getting different instances for each request. I've tested by adding a GUID property to my dependency that's initialized on the dependency constructor. And each request get's the dependency with a new GUID. Using WebApi  v2.2 and Autofac v3.5.2 and "Autofac WebApi 2.2 Integration" v3.4.0

Comment: @andyroschy - You are correct. Not sure what I was thinking when I posted this. I am removing the part about lifetime.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Well, according to the official Autofac documentation you were correct http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#no-per-request-filter-dependencies-in-web-api , there's even a GitHub issue where it says so https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/525
So i'm not sure if it's something that changed on Autofac but the documentation wasn't updated, or something that change on the WebApi framework. Or if it's something that works while Debuggin but not on when deployed, which worries me a bit.

Comment: Hmm...Well, WebApi and MVC are completely different frameworks, each with their own separate configuration. I suppose the original answer was correct because the action filters in each framework are similar - I rolled it back. You might want to check the source to see how an IAutofacActionFilter is handled.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Oh, my mistake i didn't get that this was and MVC answer and not WebApi. The documentation link i pasted refers to WebApi though ,so i'm still confused, i'll have to dig further on this. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, this whole question (and answer) is about WebApi, not MVC. I looked at the tags, and it is incorrectly tagged `asp.net-mvc` (and not webapi), so I made an incorrect assumption. But the advice about `IAutofacActionFilter` still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the steps described in the [AutoFac documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html?highlight=mvc#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters) in order to use the IoC for attributes ?

> **Enable Property Injection for Action Filters**
>
> To make use of property injection for your filter attributes call the `RegisterFilterProvider()` method on the `ContainerBuilder` before building your container and providing it to the `AutofacDependencyResolver`.
>
> ```
> builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation and seeing other examples on this site eg:

[autofac-attribute-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906329/autofac-attribute-injection-failing-on-attributes) and
[how to use property injection with autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600440/how-to-use-property-injection-with-autofac), it seems that what you need is:

```
builder.RegisterType<IMyclass>().As<MyClass>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: seems that from reading the documentation, it is not that straight forward: http://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/integration/webapi.html#provide-filters-via-dependency-injection